# How do you find the side length of an equilateral triangle if you know the side length of a square inscribed in it?

Tags: geometry

I came across a problem where a square of side length 1 inscribed in an equilateral triangle. What is the side length of the triangle?

Comment: Have you drawn a picture?  The square sits at the center of one side of the triangle and the other two vertices are on the other two sides.  There are $30-60-90$ triangles around, use them.

Answer (score 0):

When you draw a picture, the calculation sees straight forward.

Let the bottom of the square be on the middle of the bottom of the triangle.

Let the bottom of the triangle be  $$1+2a$$ then the other sides of the triangle are each $$1+\sqrt {1+a^2}$$

Thus we have $$1+2a = 1+\sqrt {1+a^2}$$

Solve for $a$ and you get $$a=\frac {\sqrt 3}{3}$$

Therefore the side of your triangle is $$ 1+\frac {2\sqrt 3}{3}$$